# Autocomplete Systemverilog in VIM

Tags: vim, autocomplete, system-verilog, folding, auto-indent

I am using VIM as the editor for SystemVerilog. I have three questions.

In some posts I saw there is a auto-complete function for VIM.

1.How can I enable auto-complete function for my Systemverilog files in VIM??

2.How can I auto-indent a selected portion in VIM?

3.How can I enable folding in VIM?

I am using plugin created by [Nachum Kanovsky](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=4743) in VIM for Systemverilog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try out my [verilog_systemverilog.vim](https://github.com/vhda/verilog_systemverilog.vim) fork where I try to implement this functionality.

Note: this functionality still has limitations, so please open issues requesting features and/or reporting bugs.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case, make sure you have these two lines in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

Assuming the linked plugin is installed and working correctly this will get you proper indenting and syntax highlighting for every supported language.

1. I can't find a Systemverilog-specific omnicompletion script on vim.org but you can still use basic syntax-based completion. Add these lines to your `~/.vimrc`:

   ```
   augroup Systemverilog
       autocmd!
       autocmd FileType systemverilog setlocal omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
   augroup END
   ```

   The completion menu is activated by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> in succession.

   See `:help ins-completion`.
2. "Auto indenting" should happen automatically. If you want "formatting", select a few lines and press `=`.
3. Modify the autocommand above:

   ```
   augroup Systemverilog
       autocmd!
       autocmd FileType systemverilog setlocal omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete foldmethod=indent
   augroup END
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
but the indents are not working..
whether I have to add :set folding indent 
in vimrc??